# How does java collection covariance work in a wrapper class?

Tags: java, generics, covariance

I think I have a decent understanding of covariance in java when it comes to `List<Base>` and `List<? extends Base>`.  I ran into an issue where I was using a wrapper class (`LiveData` in this case) and it's not working how I expected it to.

I duplicated the issue in a java repl:

```
import java.util.List;

class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    List<? extends Sub0> test0 = List.of(new C());

    List<Sub1> test1 = List.of(new Sub1());

    List<? extends Base> x = test0;
    x = test1;
    
    Holder<List<? extends Sub0>> ha = new Holder(test0);
    Holder<List<Sub1>> hb = new Holder(test1);

    Holder<List<? extends Base>> z = ha;
    z = hb;
    
  } 
}

interface Base {}

abstract class Sub0 implements Base {}

class Sub1 implements Base {}

class C extends Sub0 {}

class Holder<T> {
  T obj;
  public Holder(T obj){
  this.obj = obj;
  }
}
```

The `x = test0` and `x = test1` lines compile as I would expect, but the `z = ha` and `z = hb` do not, and I'm not really sure why.